# Mysql query with select distinct with 1 set

Tags: mysql

I have the following table tab1

```
+------+------+
|app   |val   |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+ 
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
```

I need MySQL query with the result as the following from tab1

```
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+ 
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
```

I need MySQL query with the result as the following from tab1

ie, select 1 distinct values from column app first and then select other sets of distinct values and so on

Comment: you question is not clear  ..  how the distinct app values must be related  to the others for order ???

Comment: what do you mean by distinct ?? do you need to sort something like that

Comment: i need column 'app' 's  value as 1,2,3 ,1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a row number based on app and then order

```
SELECT S.*
FROM
(
SELECT T.*,
        IF (T.APP <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
        @P:=T.APP P
FROM T 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) R 
ORDER BY APP
) S
ORDER BY RN,APP;
```

Result

```
+------+------+------+------+
| app  | val  | RN   | P    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    |    1 |    1 |
|    2 | B    |    1 |    2 |
|    3 | B    |    1 |    3 |
|    1 | B    |    2 |    1 |
|    2 | A    |    2 |    2 |
|    3 | A    |    2 |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**But** I'm not convinced that the val would always be the correct val since data is not stored in any particular order and there is no way to force an order given the sample data provided. If there is a way of establishing order in the data such as an auto_increment field or a timestamp then you should use that in the solution.